# rewrite rule for .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am Required to write rule for redirection in my website.and i am using codeigniter.so it will use index.php for all pages.
So my first rule i used is

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`.

now i want to add some thing more which are follows.

My requirement first:

input - `example.com/index.php/search/query`

url to be redirected - `example.com/search?q=query`

And,

input - `example.com/index.php/search/query&c=abc&s=xyz&p=1`

url to be redirected - `example.com/search?q=query&c=abc&s=xyz&p=1`

Thats it.

Can Anyone crack code for this.? Please...

Thanks in Advance.

Edited: Tell some reference website to know more about rules and condition syntax to write .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you html code you must write like this:

```
<a href='http://www.domain.com/index/211/title-goes-here'>url_text</a>
```

and in the htaccess file adapt the following:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php?action=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(member)-([0-9-]+)$ index.php?action=member&id=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9-]+)$ index.php?action=$1&saction=$2&sid=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9-]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/(.*).html$ index.php?action=details&id=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3&p3=$4 [NC,L]
```

using () you mark the data that you need to extract and work with it;

using $x, where x=1,2,3, ...

$x is the value

the more () you have, the more $x you have

with: RewriteRule ^(member)-([0-9-]+)$ index.php?action=member&id=$2 [NC,L]

(member) is $1 and ([0-9]+) is $2

do you understand?

Comment: thanks for the vote, but do you understand what I wrote there?